# Problems with parameters being modified across classes java

Tags: java, class

I am trying to finish my coding assignment. I need to have the game let the user input stats for their pokemon and make them battle. I have finished the stat input portion and battle method to make them battle. Now I am having issues with the battle itself. The battle must go until one player is dead or at 10 rounds it ends with a draw.

The issue I'm having is getting my rounds to run properly and make sure the damage is inflicted correctly. I believe the issue lies with my attack boolean and I am unsure of how to correct it.

My desired output:

```
Player 1, build your Pokemon!
=====================
Please name your pokemon: Berzerker 

How many hit points will it have? (1-50): 50

Split fifty points between attack level and defense level
Enter your attack level (1-49): 49

Enter your defense level (1-1): 1

Player 2, build your Pokemon!
=====================
Please name your pokemon: Paladin

How many hit points will it have? (1-50): 50

Split fifty points between attack level and defense level
Enter your attack level (1-49): 1

Enter your defense level (1-49): 49

Player 1 will roll a D2, to decides who goes first.
Player 1 rolls a 2 and will go second


Round 1!

Paladin is attacking Berzerker
Paladin rolls an attack bonus of 10
Berzerker rolls a defense bonus of 9
The attack hits dealing 3-D6 damage!
The rolls are are 6, 6, and 2 totalling: 14 damage!
Berzerker has 36 hit points left
Berzerker is attacking Paladin
Berzerker rolls an attack bonus of 20
Paladin rolls a defense bonus of 1
The attack hits dealing 3-D6 damage!
The rolls are are 3, 1, and 2 totalling: 6 damage!
Paladin has 44 hit points left
```

I have most of that but mine stops before the battle occurs.

My output

```
Player 1, build your Pokemon!
======================
Please name your Pokemon: 
Linux
How many hit points will it have? (1-50): 
50
Split fifty points between attack level and defense level
Enter your attack level (1-49): 
40
Enter your defense level (1 - 10): 
10
Player 1, build your Pokemon!
======================
Please name your Pokemon: 
Windows
How many hit points will it have? (1-50): 
50
Split fifty points between attack level and defense level
Enter your attack level (1-49): 
40
Enter your defense level (1 - 10): 
10
Player 1 will roll a D2 to see who goes first.
Exception in thread "main" Player 1 will go first.
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    This method must return a result of type boolean

    at Pokemon.attack(Pokemon.java:27)
    at Colosseum.main(Colosseum.java:31)
```

My main Class

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Colosseum 
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {

        Pokemon player1 = new Pokemon();
        Pokemon player2 = new Pokemon();
        Dice d2 = new Dice(2);
        int rounds = 10;


        userBuild(player1);//Build pokemon 1
        userBuild(player2);//Build pokemon 2

        System.out.println("Player 1 will roll a D2 to see who goes first.");
        d2.roll();// Rolls die to see who will go first
        if(d2.roll() == 1)
        {
        System.out.println("Player 1 will go first.");
        }
        else
        {
        System.out.println("Player 1 rolls a 2 and will go second");    
        }

        while(rounds <=10 && player_dead == false)
        for(int i = 0; i <= rounds; i++)//Counts the number of rounds and offers endgame scenario
        {
            System.out.println("Round"+ i + "!");
            if(d2.roll() == 1)
            {
                player1.attack(player2);
            }
            else
            {
                player2.attack(player1);
            }
        if(i == 10 && (player1.player_dead == false || player2.player_dead == false))
            {
                System.out.println("Both fighters are still standing! It's a draw!");
            }

        }


    }

    public static void userBuild(Pokemon p)//The class to build pokemon
    {
        Scanner kbinput = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name;
        int hitpoints;
        int attack;
        int defense;

        System.out.println("Player 1, build your Pokemon!");
        System.out.println("======================");
        System.out.println("Please name your Pokemon: ");//Set the pokemon name
        p.setName(name = kbinput.nextLine());
        System.out.println("How many hit points will it have? (1-50): ");//Get the pokemon hit points
        p.setHP(hitpoints = kbinput.nextInt());
        while(hitpoints <= 1 || hitpoints > 50)
        {
            System.out.println("Sorry. You must pick a number between 1 and 50: ");
            p.setHP(hitpoints = kbinput.nextInt());
        }

        System.out.println("Split fifty points between attack level and defense level");
        System.out.println("Enter your attack level (1-49): ");//Get attack level
        p.setAttack(attack = kbinput.nextInt());
        while(attack > 49 || attack < 1)//Error code if they give out of bounds answer
        {
            System.out.println("Sorry. The attack must be between 1 and 49: ");
            p.setAttack(attack = kbinput.nextInt());
        }
        System.out.println("Enter your defense level (1 - " + (50 - attack)+"): ");//Get defense level
        p.setDefense(defense = kbinput.nextInt());
        while(defense > (50-attack) || defense < 1)//Error code if they give out of bounds answer
        {
            System.out.println("Sorry. The defense must be between 1 and " + (50 - attack)+ ": " );
            p.setDefense(defense = kbinput.nextInt());
        }


    }
}
```

Dice Class

```
import java.util.Random;
public class Dice 
{
    private final int numSides;
    Random myRand = new Random();

    public Dice(int sides)
    {
        numSides = sides;
    }

    public int roll()
    {   
        int roller = (myRand.nextInt(numSides)+1);
        return roller;
    }

}
```

Pokemon Class

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Pokemon 
{
    int hp;
    int attacklevel;
    int defenselevel;
    String pokemon_name;
    Dice d6;
    Dice d20;
    boolean player_dead = false;
    Dice da1 = new Dice(6);
    Dice da2 = new Dice(6);
    Dice da3 = new Dice(6);


    public Pokemon()
    {
        hp = 0;
        attacklevel = 0;
        defenselevel = 0;
        pokemon_name = "";
        Dice d6 = new Dice(6);
        Dice d20 = new Dice(20);
        player_dead = false;
    }

    public boolean attack(Pokemon opponent)//The attack component
    {
        int attackbonus = d20.roll();
        int defensebonus = d20.roll();
        int damage;
        //Fill damage array with values for damage

        System.out.println(pokemon_name + "is attacking" +opponent.getName());

        if((attacklevel+attackbonus) > (opponent.defenselevel+defensebonus))//See if attack will miss or not
        {


            damage = (da1.roll()+da2.roll()+da3.roll());//Calculates damage from 3 random d6 rolls

            System.out.println("The attack hits dealing 3-D6 damage.");
            System.out.println("The rolls are "+ da1 +", "+ da2 +", and "+da3 + "totalling: " + damage);


            boolean hit = true;//Boolean to determine of opponent is hit or not
            opponent.hp = opponent.hp - damage;

            if(hit == true)//If attack lands
            {
                if(opponent.hp>0)
                {
                    System.out.println(opponent.getName()+ " has " + opponent.hp + "hitpoints left");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println(opponent.getName() + "has been defeated!");
                    return (player_dead = true);
                }
            }


        }
        else//If attack misses
        {
            System.out.println(pokemon_name + "'s attack has missed.");
        }

    }

        public void setHP(int hitpoints)
        {
            hp = hitpoints;
        }

        public void set

        public void setAttack(int attack)
        {
            attacklevel = attack;
        }

        public void setDefense(int defense)
        {
            defenselevel = defense;
        }

        public void setName(String name)
        {
            pokemon_name = name;
        }

        public int getHP()
        {
            return hp;
        }

        public int getAttack()
        {
            return attacklevel;
        }

        public int getDefense()
        {
            return defenselevel;
        }

        public String getName()
        {
            return pokemon_name;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You never asked an actual question.  Please narrow down your question and post only code which is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your code:

1. the outer `while`-loop for the fight (`while(rounds <=10 && player_dead == false)`)
2. `pokemon.attack(Pokemon)` has return type `boolean` but never returns anything

How to fix these:
1.: Simply remove the outer `while`-loop and add the condition that the battle ends as soon as one player is dead as condition to loop in the `for`-loop. `for(int i = 0; i <= rounds && !player_dead; i++)` after the loop you can add a condition `if(!player_dead) //draw`

2.: Since the boolean that should be returned by `attack` isn't used in any way, simply change the returntype to `boolean`.

But since you didn't ask any **question** it's hard to answer whatever you want to know. Hope this helps though.

Comment: 1. That makes sense I have made the changes to reflect it.                                 2. I do not get what you mean. I'm already using a return boolean.